# JavaScript Drawing library for Flow charts and attaching data to the view dynamically

Tags: javascript, jsplumb, cytoscape.js, jointjs

I am looking for a JavaScript Library where in I can make a simple flow chart, that includes,

A Start Point,
A End Point,
Few conditions,
Changing the data, and adding it to the view when you double click the box,
Can Fork the flow.

Went through few libraries.

D3.js is not suited very well for this kind of visualization.
Other libraries, JSplumb, Cytoscape, jointJS (And not rappid. Looking for an Open Source)

Any suggestions.

Comment: you can try this https://adrai.github.io/flowchart.js/

Comment: Would prefer a library where in the user can add nodes, and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions you listed are either generic graph theory libraries or generic Visio/Dia-like diagramming libraries.  For each, you'll have to add your own logic on top for the restricted flow chart case.

Or, you'll have to do some in-depth searching to find something that's only for flow charts.

Comment: Found bpmn-io, that can be used for the above mentioned requirements. Will have to change the source code a bit, and make few changes.